# can't create view for this query(Mysql)

Tags: view

create view police_off as

Select Job_Title, (select avg(Regular_pay) from EmpSalary where Job_Title = 'Police officer') from EmpSalary group by Job_Title having Job_Title ='police officer';

select * from police_off

error: Msg 4511, Level 16, State 1, Procedure police_off, Line 2 [Batch Start Line 26]
Create View or Function failed because no column name was specified for column 2.

Completion time: 2023-07-20T10:07:03.0120502+05:30

I try to create a view for above query But I can't create a view for the query. I've included the error message